# Unable to link 2 react js components (Login and Signup)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a total beginner to Reactjs. I created 2 components, one is Login, the other is Signup.
what i Want to do is to link the 2. For example in the login form i want to have a link saying:"New User? Register here" and when the user clicks on register here, i want the Login module to disappear and the Signup module to appear. i also want to do it the other way, Ie i want the user to be able to go to the login module via the link given below the Signup Module.

I tried using  with 'to' attribute but nothing renders on screen. have no clue how to solve this

Here is the Sign Up component:

```
import React, { isValidElement, useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
export default function Signup() {

  const [password, setPassword] = useState(''); 
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(''); 
  
  function setPass(val)
  {
    setPassword(val.target.value);
  }

  function setMail(val)
  {
    setEmail(val.target.value);
    
  }

  function validation()
 {
  let obj=
  {
    isValidEmail:false,
    isValidPassword:false
  };
     obj.isValidPassword= /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,9})/.test(password);
     obj.isValidEmail= /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,})+$/.test(email);
     return obj;
 }

function onSubmit()
{
  var validation_obj=validation();
  if(!validation_obj.isValidEmail)
  {
    
    alert("Please enter a valid email address.")
  }
  if(!validation_obj.isValidPassword)
  {
    alert("Password should have minimum 8 characters, consisting of at least one digit, one lower case, one upper case and one special character")
  }

  
}
  return (
             
    <div className="main">
    <div className="sub-main">
      
     <div>
       <h1>Sign-up</h1>
       <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" className="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" className="mail" onChange={setMail}/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" className="Uname"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" className="pass" onChange={setPass}/>
    
    </div>
    <div>
      <button className="button" onClick={onSubmit}>Create Account</button>
    </div>
      <div className="link">
        
      <p>Have Account?<a href=""> Login Here</a></p>
      

        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  )
}
```

And this is the Login Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, Router } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="sub-main">
      
       <div>
         <h1>Login</h1>
         <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" className="name"/>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" className="pass"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className="button">Login</button>
      </div>
        <div className="link">
        <p>New User?<a href="./Signup"> Register Here</a></p>
      
          </div>
        
         </div>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each component should render the `Link` component instead of the raw anchor `<a>` tag, with the target path passed on the `Link` component's `to` prop.

Signup

```
<p>Have Account?<Link to="/login">Login Here</Link></p>
```

Login

```
<p>New User?<Link to="/signup">Register Here</Link></p>
```

Then both `Signup` and `Login` components should be rendered on routes within a router component. This allows the app to navigate between these two routes, and any other routes the app is rendering.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const App = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        ...
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
        ...
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The issue i am facing is that whenever i include browser router or routes or route tag, everything from my screen disappears. the previously rendered Signup component disappears and it's just a blank screen. upon inspecting the page i get the error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.   The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component.

Comment: @Maverick125 I see. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live? Sounds like you are breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) by trying to call a React hook outside a React function component or custom React hook.